# Adding borders to grid using styles

Tags: xaml, wpf-controls

I am trying to add a double border to a grid row, so simulate a sunken panel inside the window.

Here is what I have so far, and it looks close to what I want.

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Border x:Name="TopShadowBorder" 
                    BorderBrush="#FFB7B6B6" BorderThickness="2,3,2,0" 
                    Padding="0" CornerRadius="5 5 20 20" ClipToBounds="True" Margin="-1,0,1,0" Panel.ZIndex="2">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Direction="270" ShadowDepth="2" />
                </Border.Effect>
            </Border>
                <Border x:Name="InsetBorder" BorderBrush="#FFF7F7F7" BorderThickness="2,0,2,3" 
                    CornerRadius="10" Margin="0" Panel.ZIndex="2"/>
            </Grid>
```

Is it possible to get this into a style that be shared across other grids? Something like this?

```
<Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Style={StatisResource SunkenBorder}></Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grid is a panel and you can not set Template(Changing the appearance of element) for panel.You can change template of the panel Using [Contentcontrol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx)

```
<Window.Resources>
   <ControlTemplate x:Key="GridBorderTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Border x:Name="TopShadowBorder" 
                BorderBrush="#FFB7B6B6" BorderThickness="2,3,2,0" 
                Padding="0" CornerRadius="5 5 20 20" ClipToBounds="True" Margin="-1,0,1,0" Panel.ZIndex="2">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect Direction="270" ShadowDepth="2" />
                </Border.Effect>
            </Border>
            <Border x:Name="InsetBorder" BorderBrush="#FFF7F7F7" BorderThickness="2,0,2,3" CornerRadius="10" Margin="0" Panel.ZIndex="2"/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ContentControl   Template="{StaticResource GridBorderTemplate}">
        <Grid></Grid>
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Template="{StaticResource GridBorderTemplate}">
        <Grid></Grid>
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly i could not use @Heena Patil answer, because there was no ContentPresenter.
I went with a solution based on Styles instead of Template from [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32047540/2351407)

```
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="SunkenBorder" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Grid>
              <Border x:Name="TopShadowBorder" 
                BorderBrush="#FFB7B6B6" BorderThickness="2,3,2,0" 
                Padding="0" CornerRadius="5 5 20 20" ClipToBounds="True" Margin="-1,0,1,0" Panel.ZIndex="2">
                <Border.Effect>
                  <DropShadowEffect Direction="270" ShadowDepth="2" />
                </Border.Effect>
              </Border>
              <Border x:Name="InsetBorder" BorderBrush="#FFF7F7F7" BorderThickness="2,0,2,3" CornerRadius="10" Margin="0" Panel.ZIndex="2"/>
              <ContentPresenter />
            </Grid>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>

  <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource SunkenBorder}">
    <Label>test</Label>
  </ContentControl>
```