# WPF write ControlTemplate for a ContentControl when its content type is UserControl

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I have a `ContentControl` like this:

```
<ContentControl>
    <userControls:TestControl/>
</ContentControl>
```

OR like this *[when i have PRISM system]*:

```
<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="TestView"/>
```

I see the final `UserControl` *well* until this step when i start the program.

In the above samples the `Content` type is `UserControl`. Now i want give a `ControlTemplate` to this `ContentControl`. Then i created a `style` named `StyleTest` and used it in my Xaml:

```
<ContentControl    Style="{StaticResource StyleTest}"> .....
```

My style:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleTest" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="10">
                    <Border CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="#ffffffff" BorderThickness="5">
                        <StackPanel>

                            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>

                            <TextBlock>Some additional text to test template</TextBlock>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But when i start the program the `UserControl` can not be seen and i just see this text and a border around it:      *Some additional text to test template*

- What i must write instead of above line of code to see my `UserControl` again with a white border around it?
- Why the `UserControl` not showing with above code (above style)?

Answer (score 2):

There are 3 ways to do this.

```
- by setting the ContentTemplate
- by setting the Template
- or using the Border directly and apply a style.
```

In *this* case I would use the Border and apply a style because it looks like the ContentControl is only used to do add a styled Border.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="BorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ContentTemplateStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">
                            <!--  Bind to the DataContext of the DataTemplate which is the Content of the ContentControl  -->
                            <!-- <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />-->
                            <!--  TemplateBinding improves performance  -->
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            <!--  Using the TemplatedParent  -->
                            <!--<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>-->
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="ControlTemplateStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                        <Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource ContentTemplateStyle}">
        <Button>ContentTemplateStyle</Button>
    </ContentControl>
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource ControlTemplateStyle}">
       <Button>ControlTemplateStyle</Button>
    </ContentControl>
    <Border Style="{StaticResource BorderStyle}">
        <Button>BorderStyle</Button>
    </Border>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

datacontext is a type?. Normally it will be inherited in the visual tree so I think it should be left blank.
Content is the content of the parent. Normally you can use a template binding or set the content source property.

but using this template will only show you a white border around content. The original template is lost. So you should provide the entire template for the control.

Now maybe the control contains margin and border properties and you can set those from your style and leave the original template in place.

Comment: No, datacontext is not type! Its type is UserControl... I removed it from my question. there is not any change in final result. The white border is in my template not in my UserControl! Do you undrestand my question? With this style my UserControl not  showing...

Comment: It is replacing the template with a white border. You cannot add a white border. So either provide the entire template or style it using the available properties. (And your content being a binding should be a template binding or be left out also. Or use content source...

Comment: You can use blend to extract the template and change that.

Comment: I tested `TemplateBinding`, `Binding`, `Binding Content`,... Result: I can not see my `UserControl`. The `ContentControl` is empty _WHEN_ i use the above style.

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake place and changed this part of my codes:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleTest" TargetType="ContentControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
```

To this one:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleTest" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate >
```

When i play with Template its effects is on `inner content` of the `ContentControl` (in this question: template of the `UserControl`) But when i play with `ContentTemplate`, its effects is on `ContentControl` layout.

ContentPresenter tag is same and it works now...

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
```